# Regarding sorting a character array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array lets say Having values

```
Char Arr[] ={A,B,A,C,D,B,A,F,G,B,A};
```

and I want to sort this array in the form

```
Arr[] = {A,A,A,A,B,B,B,C,D,F,G}
```

Please advise how to achieve this in java,..!!

Comment: What have you tried?? And by the way.. `Char` is no type in Java.. Its `char`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string to char and sort in descending order (ascii)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800698/converting-string-to-char-and-sort-in-descending-order-ascii)

Answer (score 1):

Trying using the method sort()..

`Arrays.sort(Arr);`

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5b%5d%29) method which can do the work for you.

```
Arrays.sort(Arr);
```

This will sort your objects in order, there is no return type, as a copy of reference is passed and is used to manipulate the array.

Comment: @Gigaquad.. `pass by reference` -> Just to mention.. There is no Pass by reference in Java.. Everything is passed by value..

Comment: @Gigaquad.. I have edited your answer to make more sense..